# Access values from another thread? Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, java-threads

I am programming an app with Kotlin using Android Studio.
I want to open a specific URL to check if a value in it is true or false (SmartHome Stuff) and then change the color of a button in my app. When doing this on the main thread Kotlin throws an android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.
So I created a new thread to do all the URL action over there and it is working (everything fine until here).

The problem is that I somehow need to get the value from the second thread into my main thread to change the button color. Or to "get" the button into the second thread and change the button color there.

I´m pretty new to programming so I´m probably not aware about easy ways of fixing my problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Concurrency in Java can be a complex subject.  Usually on a device like Android it's been simplified by library functions, but you've shown us no code so we don't know what function you're having problems with.  Show some code please, and read up on concurrency: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the coroutine, we use withContext to switch to the background thread (Dispatchers.IO) for the URL request and then switch back to the main thread to update the button color using the updateButtonColor function.`import kotlinx.coroutines.*

```
// Assuming you're inside an activity or a fragment
val myButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.my_button)

// Create a coroutine scope
val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

// Function to perform the URL request and get the value (true or false)
suspend fun performURLRequest(): Boolean {
    // Perform your URL request here and return the result (true or false)
    delay(2000) // Simulating a network delay for demonstration purposes
    return true
}

// Function to update the button color based on the value
fun updateButtonColor(value: Boolean) {
    if (value) {
        myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
    } else {
        myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
    }
}

// Launch a coroutine in the main thread
coroutineScope.launch {
    // Switch to the background thread for the URL request
    val value = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        performURLRequest()
    }

    // Now, switch back to the main thread to update the button color
    updateButtonColor(value)
}
`
```

Comment: If you were in an Activity or Fragment, you would use `lifecycleScope` for this rather than risking leaking your whole activity or fragment to a spare CoroutineScope that is never cancelled. Also, if the suspend function had blocking code, the withContext call should be inside the suspend function, not in the coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Volatile

private var flag: Boolean = false

fun toggleFlag() {

flag = !flag

}

fun performAction() {

if (flag) {

// Code execution when the flag is true

} else {

// Code execution when the flag is false

}

}
```

In this code, flag is declared as volatile. Multiple threads can call toggleFlag() to change its value, and performAction() uses the flag to decide which code path to take. With volatile, we ensure that any updates made by one thread are instantly seen by others. It's like using a special megaphone that ensures everyone hears the latest message.

Comment: Volatile in this case does not ensure that updates will be seen instantly. Especially `toggleFlag` method which is not atomic, since it performs two operations - reading a flag and writing to a flag